# How do I return absolute coordinates for bounding boxes with CustomVision API?

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I'm wondering whether it is possible for the Azure Cognitive Custom Vision Prediction API to return absolute coordinates instead of percentile based ones:

[image]

In the above screenshot, you can see the top, left, width and height properties of the prediction results.

Is there any way to let the API return absolute coordinates instead of - what I assume - percentage wise coordinates?

Extra: does anyone have an idea why it returns this type of coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of getting absolute values in the current API.

You just have to multiply those relative values by your image width / height. I made an answer about that a moment ago, you can have a look at it here: [How to use Azure custom vision service response boundingBox to plot shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794707/how-to-use-azure-custom-vision-service-response-boundingbox-to-plot-shape/50799050#50799050)

For your extra question: I guess the result is in relative because the processing is scaling/resizing the image to specific ratio. As you can see in the sample of the consumption of an exported Custom Vision model [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-model-python?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#resize-down-to-256x256), they are rescaling the image to a 256x256 square