# What measure are the coordinates for method ImageRegionCreateEntry in azure sdk cognitive custom vision?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.training.models.imageregioncreateentry?view=azure-dotnet) provides this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/customvision/training3.4preview/create-image-regions/create-image-regions?tabs=HTTP) . I am training for object detection project type.

```
"regions": [
{
  "imageId": "4d6eb844-42ee-42bc-bd6f-c32455ef07c9",
  "tagId": "b607964f-7bd6-4a3b-a869-6791fb6aab87",
  "left": 0.25,
  "top": 0.25,
  "width": 0.25,
  "height": 0.25
},
```

are these 4 measures (left, top, width, height) in centimeters, say 0.25 cm from the [left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.training.models.imageregioncreateentry.left?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision-training-models-imageregioncreateentry-left)? or are these in units, so it's 25% off the left and also has 25% width from the left?

Comment: See my answer regarding bounding box in the reply: it's the same, it is relative coordonates / width and height: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794707/how-to-use-azure-custom-vision-service-response-boundingbox-to-plot-shape/50799050#50799050

Comment: Thank you, I have responded / requestioned on the above mentioned url too.